# SuiteCRM convert numbers to words

Tags: suitecrm

Moving from Vtiger to Suitecrm. In Vtiger was option for pdf templates like:

```php
$summaryModel->set("summaryGrandTotalLiteral", $this->num2str($final_details['grandTotal'], false, $currency));
```

As a result in PDF form "total 1 USD" was shown as "one dollar" so there was possibility to display amount/numbers to words/text.
How Can I realize it in SuiteCrm. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such thing in SuiteCRM.

You will have to get the quote/invoice currency, de translation for the `summaryGrandTotalLiteral` from `$app_strings` and concatenate that yourself.

The PDF parsing is done in this file, maybe you can get more acquainted taking a look to the file in github:
https://github.com/salesagility/SuiteCRM/blob/e523df75ffaeaa593a1eebb4f7306b9e9c81759c/modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/generatePdf.php